# Expected value in terms of CDF

Tags: statistics

I am completely new to statistics but find myself stuck at a point. Will appreciate some help.

I see the following relation between expected value and CDF for a non negative R.V.:
\begin{equation}
E[X]=\int_0^\infty(1-F_X(x))dx
\end{equation}
My question is that if my R.V. has support in $[0,1]$, but I need to find conditional expected value of X between $[0,a]$, a<1 will the above equality hold if I replace $\infty$ with $a$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: integrate by part $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_a^b x f(x) dx$

Comment: For a random variable $X$ with support on $[0,a]$, $$\int_a^\infty (1-F_X(x)) dx=0$$ since $F_X(x)=1$ for $x \geq a$

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately for me, I had missed out an important detail. Will it be asking too much for you to look into it again? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1952009: Thanks a lot for your response. But my problem seems to be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If $Y$ is a random variable with $P\left(Y\leq x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\mid X\leq a\right)$
for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X\leq a\right)=\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{Y}\left(y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{a}1-\frac{F_{X}\left(x\right)}{F_{X}\left(a\right)}dx$$

Comment: thank you so very much. This is the second time you have helped me with a major block. Thank you very much, I was hoping that you will see this post and comment. :)

Comment: You are welcome, and I am glad to help.

Comment: thank you once again for your answer, but now I need to cite the source. I have tried to find it in some book, but could not. can you please suggest some source (book/article) which I can cite in my study? Unfortunately I cannot just cite the forum. Please help.

Comment: It was decennia ago when I red about stuff like this in books or syllabi. I am afraid I can't help you on this.